# school bus tracking gps web app

Tags: javascript, gps

i am developing one school management application in php.for that i need to develop one module like school bus tracking.but i am new to this topic.
i have gone through so many searches.but no luck.

```
<script>
    var watchID = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var optn = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: Infinity,
            maximumAge: 0
        };
        if (navigator.geolocation)
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fail, optn);
        else
            $("p").html("HTML5 Not Supported");
        $("button").click(function() {

            if (watchID)
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);

            watchID = null;
            return false;
        });

    });

    function success(position) {
        var googleLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);
        var mapOtn = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: googleLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
        };

        var Pmap = document.getElementById("map");

        var map = new google.maps.Map(Pmap, mapOtn);
        addMarker(map, googleLatLng);
    }

    function addMarker(map, googleLatLng, title, content) {
        var markerOptn = {
            position: googleLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptn);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content,
            position: googleLatLng
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });
    }
</script>
```

i found this code.but this code shows map of my location.but i want to track a bus location.how can i get location of a bus.and which tracker device is preferable to use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the php?

Comment: i am not using any php script to this.

Comment: Excatly. So why was php taged?

Comment: i am doing this project in php.so i mentioned.

Comment: _“how can i get location of a bus.and which tracker device is preferable to use?”_ - well the first one kinda depends on the second one, don’t you think? And before you have decided which hardware to use, it makes little sense to even come here - you do not have any specific programming question to ask at this point. So go figure out the technical aspects/“hardware side” of the tracking first of all. Only then does it make sense to ask how to get the location, because only then will you know which interfaces/APIs you will have to work with.

Comment: Hey guys, take it easy on the guy. Roja. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I have managed to implement a similar app. Check here: [Tracking app](https://rosoga.ruemerc.com/)

.(Use 32003693 as credential and 6 as freight id) .
I used this script to get the location:
//i have omitted some parts of the code

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
      //alert("Geotrack working...");
    } else {
      $('#removeMessages').html('This app is not supported by this browser or OS.');
    }
  });


//setInterval(showLocation(position),10000);

function showLocation(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  var freightid = <?php echo $freightid?>; //this is used to identify the freight
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'controllers/getLocation.php', //php to save the tracked locations
    data: 'latitude=' + latitude + '&freightid=' + freightid + '&longitude=' + longitude, //data with coordinates
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg) {
        $("#location").html(msg.locationname);
        $("#lat").html(msg.lat);
        $("#lgt").html(msg.lgt);
        initializeMap(msg.lat, msg.lgt, msg.locationname, msg.locationname);
      } else {
        $("#location").html('Not Available');
        initializeMap(0, 0, "Undefined location", "Undefined country"); //where I initialize the map
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        showLocation(position); //this will send request again and again after 3 seconds or time you want. For your case i set it seconds for patients sake
      }, 1800);

    }
  });
} <
/script>

<!-- script to initialize the map and place a maker on the location obtained-->
<
script
src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=youur api key"
type = "text/javascript" > < /script> <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  //initializeMap();
  function initializeMap(custom_lat, custom_lng, title, address) {
    var locations = [

      [address, custom_lat, custom_lng, 2]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-0.2842285, 36.0729164),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var indetify = locations[i][3];
      var iconset = "http://ruralshores.com/assets/library_maps.png"
      // alert("Identify:"+indetify);
      if (indetify == 1) {
        iconset = "../dist/images/map/1.png";
      } else {
        iconset = "../dist/images/map/2.png";
      }
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

        icon: iconset,
        optimized: false
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A GPS device is preferred. A smartphone should do the trick.
Le'me know in case of any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.what is freight id?and how to give link between smartphone to our code.can we use any id of that smartphone in our code?i am new to this maps concept.so please explain

Comment: In my app, freight id is a number that identifies the journey id. You get me? I quite don't understand your 'and how to give link between smartphone to our code.can we use any id of that smartphone in our code?' question. Could you be more clear please

Comment: Have you tested the demo link I have given you?

Comment: i have tested.but it does not show any particular location.i mean dont have any marker?and why it blinks?

Comment: It blinks because i I'm fetching the location of the truck every 3 seconds. If you enable locations on your browser or mobile device, it should show your current location like: https://ibb.co/iaxhNQ

Comment: i did not get that marker.i checked it on my browser

Answer (score 0):

Run this snippet to test if geolocation is working on your device.
you can check [w3school geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) for guidance on this API.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works for me.i can get my present location coordinates.what my question is how can we get that tracker device coordinates?sorry...may be this is a silly question.but i am completely new to this concept.hope you understand.and thank you so much for reply

Comment: Its cool. So I'm guessing you got a result like:Latitude: -0.2839546
Longitude: 36.073021499999996. Let me send you a fiddle link. Give me 5

Comment: yes i got this latitude and longitude values of my present position.but now i need to track a device which is in another place.how to track it?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I have added a form to our page that has two inputs. One input for latitude and the other for latitude.

The javascript gets the location and sets the coordinates . Check the comments.
Now, to get the locations. just submit the form maybe to a php script , a servlet etc.

If you host your app, any device that has locations enabled will work.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
 document.getElementById("lat").value =position.coords.latitude;//set the value for latitude
 document.getElementById("lgt").value = position.coords.longitude;//set value for logitude
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}



function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<!-- This show the location -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="lat">
<input type="text" id="lgt">
<button type="submit" >send coordinates</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know how it works.

Have fun coding.

Comment: code is working.i am working on localhost now.is it possible to check the tracking device location in localhost?

Comment: Yeah. if you use your public ip. But there are free web hosting services. Try one.

Comment: i am getting my current location from getCurrentPosition() method?but i want  to get the position of smart phone which is located at another place? like ola .By this code the position object takes only users latitude and longitude who are open this web application.but i want to show the mobile position on the map to users.hope u understand?thank you.

Comment: Ok, so you can save the coordinates in a database. Now let me create some code to set makers in on the location from the db.Give me 30

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to draw marker on Google Maps.
Now that you can read the device coordinates, you can submit the coordinates to your server (maybe try jquery). Save this data in a database. Then retrieve the coordinates and use the snippet below. Plus, note the map will require you to get an API key. Check snippet for link.

```js
 function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -0.2842285, lng: 36.0729164};//feed coordinates here from db

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Bus Location!'
        });
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    <!--get YOUR_API_KEY here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update me on your progress...